# string matching in `MAIN()` parameters

Tags: raku

I would like to restrict an argument to `MAIN()` with a string match.
This works:

```
sub MAIN(
    Str :$r where * eq any(< aaa bbb ccc >) = "bbb"
) { say $r }

$ perl6 tb.p6 -r="ccc"
ccc
```

But this does not:

```
sub MAIN(
   Str :$r where * ~~ m:i/< aaa bbb ccc >/ = "bbb",
) { say $r }

$ perl6 ta.p6 -r="ccc"
Use of uninitialized value of type Any in string context.
Methods .^name, .perl, .gist, or .say can be used to stringify it to something meaningful.
  in whatevercode  at ta.p6 line 2
Usage:
  ta.p6 [-r=<Str where { ... }>]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The biggest problem is you used both `*` to make a WhateverCode lambda and `m`.

`m/…/` gets matched against whatever happens to be in `$_`.
This effectively happens outside of the `~~`.

If you had only used `m/…/` it would have worked

```perl6
sub MAIN(
    Str :$r where m:i/< aaa bbb ccc >/ = "bbb"
) { say $r }
```

You could have also put the `:i` inside of the regex

```perl6
/:i < aaa bbb ccc >/
```

---

A `where` clause does smartmatching, just like `~~` does smartmatching. So using both like you did is redundant.

In a smartmatch based feature the expression gets run with `$_` is set to the value being matched. The result of that expression is then matched against the input.

I'm going to use a `subset` to try and help explain it better

```perl6
subset Foo of Str where * ~~ m:i/< aaa bbb ccc >/;
```

When you are match against it the first thing that happens is the `Str` check.
(This is fairly performant, and the type specializer may be able to eliminate this check)

```perl6
'ccc' ~~ Str; # Str.ACCEPTS('ccc');
```

Then the **expression** in the `where` clause gets run with the value being checked in `$_`.

```perl6
my $result = do given 'ccc' { * ~~ m:i/< aaa bbb ccc >/ }
# $result holds a closure
```

What happens next is that the result gets smartmatched against the value being tested.

```perl6
'ccc' ~~ $result; # $result.ACCEPTS('ccc');
```

That last one in this case will depend on whatever happened to be in `$_` at the time.
Since that will now happen deep inside of the language, you might not have any control over `$_`.

In the case of a `where` clause it can be anything.

```perl6
$_ = 'fubar';

#                v--v
subset Foo where * ~~ m:i/
    { say '$_   = ', $_ }
    { say 'orig = ', $/.orig } # the string that is matched against
    < aaa bbb ccc >
/;

my $result = 'ccc' ~~ Foo;
# $_   = fubar
# orig = fubar

say $result;
# False
```

Since `'fubar'` doesn't match `/< aaa bbb ccc >/` the result is `False`.

By adding `* ~~` you also added spooky-action-at-a-distance.

It works without `* ~~`, because `Regex.ACCEPTS()` doesn't rely on `$_`.

```perl6
$_ = 'fubar';

subset Foo where m:i/
    { say '$_   = ', $_ }
    { say 'orig = ', $/.orig }
    < aaa bbb ccc >
/;

my $result = 'ccc' ~~ Foo;
# $_   = fubar
# orig = ccc

say $result
# True
```

---

There is a reason Perl 6 does two levels of code execution is for code like the following

```perl6
subset Bar where $_ eq any < aaa bbb ccc >;

my $result = do given 'ccc' { $_ eq any < aaa bbb ccc > }
# $result = True;

# 'ccc' ~~ $result;
$result.ACCEPTS('ccc');
# $result is True, and True.ACCEPTS() always returns True
```

Note that it can be shortened to:

```perl6
subset Bar where any < aaa bbb ccc >;

my $result = do given 'ccc' { any < aaa bbb ccc > }
# $result = any < aaa bbb ccc >;

# 'ccc' ~~ $result;
$result.ACCEPTS('ccc');
# any(< aaa bbb ccc >).ACCEPTS('ccc')
```

---

This double code execution happens for all smartmatching features.

- `~~`

  ```perl6
  'ccc' ~~ $_ eq any < aaa bbb ccc > # True.ACCEPTS('ccc')
  'ccc' ~~ any < aaa bbb ccc >       # any(…).ACCEPTS('ccc')
  ```
- `where`

  ```perl6
  subset Baz where $_ eq any < aaa bbb ccc >
  subset Baz where any < aaa bbb ccc >
  ```
- `when`

  ```perl6
  when $_ eq any < aaa bbb ccc > {…}
  when any < aaa bbb ccc > {…}
  ```

Basically this is so that you can smartmatch against a value or against an expression or against code.
(Code is really a type of value in Perl 6)

```perl6
10 ~~ 0..10;                # match against a value
10 ~~ Range.new(0,10);      # same as previous line

10 ~~ 0 ≤ * ≤ 10;           # match against code
10 ~~ -> $_ { 0 ≤ $_ ≤ 10 } # basically the same as previous line

10 ~~ 0 ≤ $_ ≤ 10;          # match against an expression with $_
                            # (not the same a previous two lines)
```

---

I want to point out that regular expressions in Perl 6 are a type of function.

```perl6
my &foo = sub ($_) {$_ eq 'abc'};

my &bar = * eq 'abc';

my &baz = /^ abc $/;

my &zzz = 'abc' # ERROR
```

So `* ~~ /…/` is creating a function from something that is already a function.
It is also turning what would be double code execution into quadruple code execution.

In `m/…/` the `m` effectively causes the regex / function to run against whatever happens to be in `$_`.

```perl6
# $_ = Any; # initial value in $_

my &code = * ~~ m/abc/;
my &code = * ~~ ($_ ~~ /abc/); # same as previous line
```

There is also `rx`, which is similar to `m` except it always returns the regex itself rather than the result of calling it. (A bare `/…/` acts like `rx/…/`)

---

Smartmatching can be confusing when you are first starting out.
I'd argue it can be confusing to people who are otherwise experts in Perl 6.
(It's still a little confusing to me, and I know how it works.)
I also did a poor job trying to explain it here, but I was trying to be relevant to your question, and your use of `~~` made it harder to explain.

To keep myself sane I try to follow a few basic rules.
These apply to `~~`, `where`, and `when`.

- Use a literal, or literal-like if possible.

  ```perl6
  … ~~ 42
  … ~~ 'a'
  … ~~ any < aaa bbb ccc >
  … ~~ 1..10              # not actually a literal, but literal-like
  ```
- If you are using an expression make sure it can only return `True` or `False`.
  The value being matched against is in `$_` which can be helpful in the `where` clause of a `subset`.

  ```perl6
  … ~~ 0 < $_

  … ~~    $_.lc.contains('abc');    # Returns True or False
  when    $_.lc.contains('abc') {…}
  … where $_.lc.contains('abc');

  … ~~ $_.chars.Bool
  … ~~ ?$_.chars     # prefix:« ? » coerces to Bool

  … ~~ ?~$_ # coerce to Str, coerce to Bool
            # True if the Str isn't empty
            # (so has the same effect as previous two examples)
  ```

  If I had just used `$_.chars` it would only match if the value was numerically the same as the length.

  ```perl6
  '1'   ~~ $_.chars; # True
  '3.0' ~~ $_.chars; # True

  '1.0' ~~ $_.chars; # False (1.0 == 3)

  # that previous one is the same as
  do given '1.0' { $_.chars }.ACCEPTS( '1.0' ) # False
  # 3.ACCEPTS('1.0')
  ```

  This is why I recommend making sure it returns a Bool.

  There is an exception to this rule. Namely calling a routine that returns a value that you want to smart-match against.

  ```perl6
  … ~~ Date.today.day-of-week;
  ```

  (This is a bad example, but is illustrative of what I mean.)
- Use a Callable.
  This effectively removes the first (expression) layer of code execution.
  (The resulting value is whatever the result of the function is.)

  ```perl6
  … ~~ *.lc.contains('abc')
  … ~~ {.lc.contains('abc')}
  … ~~ /:i abc/              # remember that a regex is a function

  when    {.lc.contains('abc')} {…}
  … where {.lc.contains('abc')};

  sub foo ( $_ ) { .lc.contains('abc') }
  … ~~ &foo
  when &foo {…}
  … where &foo;
  ```
- Don't use `~~` in either of the other two smartmatching features.

  ```perl6
  when     * ~~ /…/ {…} # don't do this
  … where  * ~~ /…/     # don't do this either

  … where $_ ~~ /…/     # No, … just no.
  ```

  I would be a little more lenient of this one if there is a long expression, and this is only part of it.

  ```perl6
  when (.chars = 3 ?? $_ ~~ Str !! $_ ~~ Int) {…}
  ```

  I have never come across any real code where this would have been useful.

  Everytime I have seen `~~` used in a smartmatch, it would have worked better without it.

By sticking to the above rules `m:i/…/` would still work, but for a different reason.

```perl6
'ccc' ~~ m:i/ < aaa bbb ccc > /;

my $result = do given 'ccc' { m:i/ < aaa bbb ccc > / }
say $result.perl;
# Match.new(pos => 3, orig => "ccc", hash => Map.new(()), from => 0, list => (), made => Any)

$result = $result.ACCEPTS('ccc');
say $result.perl;
# Match.new(pos => 3, orig => "ccc", hash => Map.new(()), from => 0, list => (), made => Any)
```

`.ACCEPTS()` on a instance of Match always returns itself. It is also always Trueish.

It still works correctly if there is a failure to match. (It returns something that is Falseish.)

---

Again a `where` constraint, and a `when` condition are the same as the right side of `~~`.

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks. It should improve my use of `when`, where`, `~~`, and `*`.  Another thing that tripped me up, which lead to the question, was that I had assumed that `//` and `m//` where equivalent. If I had just used `//` I would not have learned as much.

Comment: @NormanGaywood There is `rx/…/` for when you want to pass the regex around as a value instead of running it immediately. It is not as commonly used as just `/…/`

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
sub MAIN(
   Str :$r where * ~~ / 'aaa' | 'bbb' | 'ccc' / = "bbb",
) { say $r }
```

`< aaa bbb ccc >` in regex is not interpolated as array, should use as this:

```
my @a = < aaa bbb ccc >;
say so "aaa" ~~ /@a/;
```

Comment: I thought I was using  "Quoted lists are LTM matches"  so `/< aaa bbb ccc >/` does work. Interestingly if I drop the m:i like in your example, my example works (without ignore case).

Comment: It seems I need: `sub MAIN(
   Str :$r where * ~~ /:i < aaa bbb ccc > / = "bbb",
) { say $r }
`